# Link on my website leads to a broken version of an otherwise-working site

Tags: php, html, hyperlink

First time poster here.

I'm putting together a website to work as a tool for a LARP I attend. I'm trying to link to specific pages on the LARP's main website in various parts of my own site.

When I follow my link, background images and other graphic assets mostly don't load.

I've noticed that if I enter the URL into my browser with a final backslash, as below, the problem occurs in Firefox and Chrome:

http://legacylarp.com/midlanders.php/

If I remove the forwardslash, the site loads just fine. The problem is, the links on my webpage only work if I have the final forwardslash.

How do I make this link work?

Feel free to check out my (rather atrociously in-progress and newbish) site, http://todd.sharonand.co.

Comment: a) That's a forward slash. b) It shouldn't be there at the end. c) "the links on my webpage only work if I have the final backslash", really?

Comment: @LeeTaylor
a)Thanks!
b)For reasons I don't understand, it wasn't working before. 
c)I'm gonna file this under "It works now, go with it."
d)Thanks again!

Comment: `myFile.php` and `myFile.php/` are two very different things. The first is a file with an extension of "php", the second is a folder.

Comment: Could be an issue related to `.htaccess`, do you use that file?

Comment: Thanks for explaining the difference, @JamesDonnelly. The LARP had a company build their page, and I am not in contact with this company, so it's up to me to work around any access to their stuff. I'm not actually familiar with .htaccess, but it seems to be working now?

Comment: @JamesDonnelly: `myFile.php/` is not necessarily a folder … could be a file `myFile.php` that is accessed by this, and the “rest” of the URL (only `/` in this case) would be considered `PATH_INFO`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you are using url rewriting.

That is not a good combination with relative paths to assets like css, images and javascript.

To make sure the paths to your assets are always correct, use absolute paths.

So:

```
/css/common.css
/images/empty.png
```

instead of:

```
css/common.css
images/empty.png
```

Comment: That's an interesting possibility. I'm gonna have to look into URL rewriting, because I'm unfamiliar with the concept. Is there any way you can show me an example of how I might change one of the URLs I'm using in order to better understand your suggestion?

Comment: @user55697 To solve your current problem you just need to use absolute paths.